# Update existing individual contact by using reference contact (search bar external sheet)

Tags: contacts, upgrade, caldera-forms, contact-reference

I'm using caldera forms and civicrm and I want to update contact informations by external forms.

The idea is to use contact reference to identify existing contact rather than adding it (first name, last name and Email).

This method works great with organization contact but with individual contact it creates a new contact rather than update the existing.

The image of search bar

[image]

Comment: just wondering if it relates to your Unsupervised dedupe Matching Rule.

Comment: is not related to dedupe rules the idea to get individual contact from search bar by (civicrm contact reference) without typing First name, Last name and email.  The purpose is to chose the contact from search bar and update informations of this one.